# How to reference the output of vite in a static mutlip-page site

Tags: node.js, vite

Using vite as the front end build tool for a new website I have to build at work. My question is how would I go about updating the references to the outputted Js and css files in a true multi page site. The site is completely static, not a single page app and no server side includes. So each html page in the site needs to have a reference to the outputted files and I don't want to manually update these references each time I do a new build.

I am pretty sure this is not something vite is designed for and I just wanted to get some advice on the best way to achieve this. I'm thinking it would need to be a node.js script to grab the outputted file names and then do some token replacement on all .html files in the root web folder.

Hope this is clear and looking forward to some advice. I'm new to vite btw so sorry if this has been asked before

I've got a working vite solution but only the index.html is generated and includes the reference to the newly generate assets, I need all html files in the root web folder to also be updated with the newly generated files

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Use Vite's `public` folder to statically serve your files:

https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#the-public-directory